# Linux batch conversion: Change quality of jpg with convert but keep its name

Tags: linux, imagemagick

If I convert my images with

```
convert -quality 80% *.jpg
```

It works, but the software changes the file names to the first one it picks. How can I keep the name or even replace the previous image with that of a lower quality.

Comment: @JimGarrison - sounds like a shell scripting question.

Comment: from the man page: 
> Mogrify overwrites the original image file, whereas, convert(1) writes to a different image file.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
mogrify -quality 80% *.jpg
```

Answer (score 17):

convert command help:

`convert input-file [options] output-file`

Now a little script to convert all jpg files to 80% quality of original under current directory

```
for file in *.jpg; do
  convert "$file" -quality 80% "$file"
done;
```

Comment: Useless use of `ls`, as it can be shortened to `for f in *jpg`. And mogrify can work on multiple files at once.

Comment: @ringbearer It's not a great way of doing it. Requires another process, and fails for files with spaces. Apart from that it's a great answer.

Comment: I removed subprocess (backtick), and add quotes to prevent errors

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you.

```
convert -quality 80% '*.jpg' -set filename:original %t %[filename:original].jpg
```